# Testing a domain for a catchAll email in node js

Tags: node.js, email, dns, sendmail, telnet

I am trying to programatically test if a domain has a catch all email address hosted on it. I would like to know if a particular domain - ie. facebook.com - would receive an email sent to blahblah@facebook.com.

I am currently using node DNS to see if the domain first has Mx records, then I send a ping to the email, unfortunately this is very slow and I was wondering if there is a faster way of detecting this.

```
validateDomain: function(domain, array, i, callback) {
    var testEmail = '1qaz2wsx3edc4rfv5tgb@' + domain;
    checkEmail(testEmail, function(validation, addresses, err) {
        if (validation) {
            callback( err, false, array, i);
        } else {
            array.push(domain);
            callback( null, true, array, i);
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I am currently set up to validate a catchall by using a very unlikely email. The function `checkEmail` uses Mx records to see if the domain has email and sends a ping. This is the function I would like to replace to detect the catch all.

Thanks,

Comment: Note that some setups may contain front-end gateways which accept messages for any address even though the actual mail servers do not recognise it (i.e. there is no address validation configured on the message gateway). In summary, there are situations where the existence of catch-all address cannot be verified.

Comment: Sorry to be a nitpick, but you use "email" incorrectly in "using a very unlikely email.". What you mean is an email *address*. An *email* is the actual text. Unfortunately many people abbreviate this incorrectly :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Catch-all email trappers aren't implemented in DNS to the best of my knowledge, they're configured at the email server level.  So there's no shortcut for testing this other than checking for the validity of an email address.

Note that you don't have to actually send an email to test.  Within, say, an SMTP session the RCPT TO command returns: 200 or 250 on success, 251 or 551 on forward, 252 cannot verify but will accept, 450 or 550 mailbox unavailable, 552 exceeded storage, 553 mailbox name not allowed.  Upon determining whether/not the wildcard exists you'd send a QUIT.

Comment: Additionally, I expect that postmasters won't like people trying to send actual emails to bogus addresses.

Comment: @Rhialto As a postmaster myself I couldn't agree more.  You'd be surprised how many of these "discovery" type emails I get.

Answer (score 0):

The [smtp-protocol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smtp-protocol#client-verify-username-cb) package has a verify username method.